# display table (solumns) information on Apache Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am learning Apache Spark SQL following this [tutorial](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/data-exploration-using-spark-sql.html) and was wondering if there is a way to show the table description (something like "describe " or "show columns from " in MySQL)?

NOTE: I am using scala 1.0

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is

```
val wikiData = sqlContext.parquetFile("../../data/wiki_parquet")
wikiData.registerAsTable("wikiData")
wikiData.schema
```